# Time Computational complexity?

Tags: c, complexity-theory, big-o

I have this sorting code below which is bubble sort, but I think this code is not exactly O(N^2) . I was wondering what would be the Time computational complexity in terms of Big O for this code below. My guess it is O(N.logN).

Code is just given here as example, not claiming it to be compilable as it is.

```
for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
    {
        if (a[j+1] < a[j])
        {
            temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j+1];
            a[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @PaulR   Blooper corrected - Posted the code now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My guess it is O(N.logN).

Why guess? Look at what's actually happening...

The first time though the outer loop, i == 0. That means that j will range from 0 to n-1.

The second time through, i == 1, so j will range from 0 to n-2.

The third time though, i == 2, so j ranges from 0 to n-3.

...

The last time through, i == n-1, so j ranges from 0 to 0.

So, the total number of operations is n-1 + n-2 + n-3 + ... + 0.

What's the sum ∑i, i=0..n-1? Now convert that to a big-O bound.

Comment: Caleb's right.  It might "feel" less than O(n^2) because the inner loop grows shorter with each iteration with the outer loop, and it is true that this is faster than if the inner loop went to "n" each time.  However, it doesn't change overall fact that the amount of work grows exponentially with n.

Comment: @Caleb Thanks for the math. Yes the total number of iterations seem to be N(N-1)/2 so I see it still is O(N^2). What would a N.logN (iterative, not recursive) algorithm look like. When we do binary search (on a sorted array) why is it said to be logN when we actually go N-->N/2 -->N/4 etc...i.e. dividing in half the array to search? People always say binary search==>logN, but I havent come across the math behind it?

Comment: @goldenmean In a binary search, you divide the number of things to search through by 2 at each step. That means that there are log2(n) steps required to find any element. Try it: if n=8, it takes 3 steps. If n=32, 5 steps.